# Фоновые задачи на сайте (Flask)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Есть необходимость создать фоновую нагрузку на сайте под управлением flask. Пример: есть метод, который выполняет определенную задачу, длительностью в 1 минуту. При этом сайт должен вернуть ответ сразу же, а задача продолжить выполняться в фоне. Я пробовал использование потоков, но они не поддерживаются pythonanywhere. Есть какое-то решение, которое сможет работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На pythonanywhere вообще туго с фоновыми задачами. По-моему, celery там тоже не работает. Лучшее решение - не использовать pythonanywhere, либо заплатить там за дополнительные возможности. Советую глянуть на aws и попробовать разместить своё приложение там. Если я правильно помню, там есть бесплатные виртуалки с минимальными характеристика на очень длительный срок использования.